# Permission error when using cat command as an editor

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command

The following command works as expected:

```
# Add/create /tmp/hosts with the string content inside EOFs
$ cat >> /tmp/hosts <<EOF
127.0.0.0 example.com
127.0.0.0 foo.example.com
EOF
```

However, the following command yields an error even when the sudo'd account has a permission to write to `/etc/hosts`.

```
$ sudo cat >> /etc/hosts <<EOF
127.0.0.0 example.com
127.0.0.0 foo.example.com
EOF

-bash: /etc/hosts: Permission denied
```

Why? And how can one achieve exactly what the above command intends to?

Comment: use sudo command before cat,go here for more http://superuser.com/questions/538760/adding-a-line-into-the-hosts-file-getting-permission-denied-when-using-sudo-m

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the provided link by: @insomniac

Following should work:

```
sudo -- bash -c 'cat << EOF >> /etc/hosts
127.0.0.0 example.com
127.0.0.0 foo.example.com
EOF'
```

Otherwise redirection is handled by current user process not by `sudo`.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you and @insomniac for the quick answer.

Comment: so you added an __invaluable answer__ given the reference to the other question. Sweet.

Comment: @devnull: Sorry you feel upset, I believe insomniac should have posted the answer not a comment.

Comment: @devnull I'm with anubhava on this.  Do look back on my original question where I specifically ask "how can one achieve exactly what the above command intends to?" The link insomniac provided does nothing do answer it.

Comment: @anubhava (1) That's not quite how SO works. (2) I'd doubt if you would understand that given how your answers often change (& are _inspired_ by) other answers in a given post.

Comment: @devnull: I have also experienced numerous instances when my answers/comments prompted other posters to change their answers but have always taken that in right spirit. OP's comment is here as well. Though I really don't want make this as a point of unnecessary arguments as I consider you (and few others) good & knowledgeable companion on this platform.